# My ionic app works fine with serve --lab but doesn't work while running on mobile

Tags: android, debugging, ionic-framework, geolocation, emulation

This is geo js file which id directly connected via index.html can you please explain me why i am unable to run. whether it is debugging problem or apk extraction problem.

my ionic project works fine with ionic serve --lab ,but while copied the.apk file in build folder to my phone and install the app but blank screen appears ,

Please can anyone suggest what might be my problem

my app is using google maps,key is provieded for both app and browser in index.html
here is my code:

```js
function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 17.3850, lng: 78.4867},
          zoom: 6
        });
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});
//var posOptions={timeout:10000, enableHighAccuracy:true};
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };


            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Here');
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
      }

      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
 <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAJWfIcxV1Q1-lG66bpqhLfBB1zevi9bG4&callback=initMap">
    </script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
 <script src="js/geo.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">

    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-royal">
        <h1 class="title">Geo Location example</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content>
   <div id="map"></div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should take a look at the console and find the errors. If your phone is running Android >= 4.4, you can access the application console via Chrome. It is explained here : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging

Comment: Not only that similarly pdf plugin also working in ionic serve--lab when opening with apk  no result is being displayed